# 'gnuplot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: gnuplot, bodegraph

First of all I found a deleted question in this forum about the topic so I don't know if there is something bad about this.

I am using Windows 10, MiKTeX, TeXstudio and I have GNUplot installed.

I am trying to graph a bode diagram using the package `bodegraph`.

After compilling I get no errors but I just got two grids drawn with no curves. I searched over the internet and found that I must add `-shell-escape` or `-enable-write18` in the command line for pdfLaTeX getting `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

After compiling again I get the warning `'gnuplot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Another search over the internet tells me that I should check if the path to `gnuplot` appears in `PATH`, I checked the LaTeX installation and found out that `gnuplot` does not appears in `PATH`.

I entered into the Windows enviroment variables and created a new one with the wgnuplo.exe localization but still doesn´t work.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{bodegraph}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=15/4]
    \begin{scope}[yscale=3/60]
    \UnitedB
    \semilog{-1}{2}{-60}{60}
    
    \BodeGraph[thick,samples=500]{-1:2}
    {-\SOAmp{7.5}{0.0182}{2.73}+
        \SOAmp{9}{0.02}{3}+
        2*\IntAmp{1}
    }
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm,yscale=3/90]
    \UniteDegre
    \OrdBode{15}
    \semilog{-1}{2}{-180}{0}
    \BodeGraph[thick,samples=500]{-1:2}
    {-\SOArg{7.5}{0.0182}{2.73}+
        \SOArg{9}{0.02}{3}+
        2*\IntArg{1}
    }
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't know what to do from here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Windows has its own environment variable called PATH. This needs to include the directory containing the gnuplot executable. I haven't used Windows for many years, but if you search for "Windows PATH environment variable" (or similar), I think you will find the information you need.

Comment: I entered into the enviroment variables of windows, It was only the gnuplot demo that I found on LaTeX instalation, I created a new one with the wgnuplot.exe localization, but did not work

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Have you installed gnuplot? Have you added the installation directory into the windows PATH environment variable? If so, what happens if you open up a command prompt and type `gnuplot`?

Comment: @IanThompson excuse me I have never experienced this issue before. 1 Yes, I have installed gnuplot. 2 I followed this process https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm to create a new system variable with the location of wgnuplot.exe. 3 when I type gnuplot into the command prompt I get the same warning: 'gnuplot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @IanThompson Problem solved during the installation I should have checked the "Add application directory to your PATH environment variable" option.

Comment: @IanThompson How do I install gnuplot from their website? Because in tair tar.gz I cannot find setup.exe or something similar to install gnuplot executable :(

Comment: @FacebFaceb --- Try [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.2.4/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an issue related to the underlying OS Windows and not to TeX.